# Modifying a VBA function to retrieve values of two columns instead of one?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that retrieves multiple values for a single look up value.

```
Public Function MultiVLookup(MatchWith As String, TRange As Range, 
col_index_num As Integer)
MatchWith = LCase$(MatchWith)
If (MatchWith = "") Then
   MultiVLookup = ""
Else
    For Each cell In TRange
        If LCase$(cell.Value) = MatchWith Then
            x = x & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & ":;"
        End If
    Next cell
    If (x = "") Then
       MultiVLookup = ""
    Else
       MultiVLookup = Left(x, Len(x) - 2)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The problem is that I have to return another value from another column in the csv file. The function works like `MultiVLookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_number)` and returns for example:

```
4' X 5'-7";5'-3" X 7'-6";8' X 11'-2
```

Based on an item number that it's matching. But I need it to return:

```
4' X 5'-7":120;5'-3" X 7'-6":80;8' X 11'-2:50
```

So I need to include `:` between each size (which is easy because it's static) but I don't know how to include the price value for each size. *So I guess I need to return the values of two columns* instead of one, e.g. **size and price** instead of just **size**.

It is related to this line that I need to change:

```
x = x & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & ": 'WHAT TO PUT HERE!? ;"
```

I just don't know how. Any tips would be very helpful here! Please let me know if you need more info!?

I don't need a full answer just a step in the right direction or some helpful insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Public Function MultiVLookup(MatchWith As String, TRange As Range, _
                             col_index_num As Integer, col_index_num2 As Integer)
Const SEP as String = ";"
Dim sp as String

    MatchWith = LCase$(MatchWith)
    If (MatchWith = "") Then
       MultiVLookup = ""
    Else
        sp = ""
        For Each cell In TRange
            If LCase$(cell.Value) = MatchWith Then
                MultiVLookup  = MultiVLookup  & _
                        sp & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & _
                       ":" & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num2).Value 
                sp = SEP
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

End Function
```